# How to get the name of a file chosen from Display.getInstance().openGallery() in Codename One?

Tags: codenameone

I want to retrieve the name of the file selected from the image gallery and opened in a label/imageviewer in my form.

I need the name since I'm saving file paths in my database and I want to concatenate that file name to a fixed path where I'm storing my images.

I haven't been able to do so, so far since Display.getInstance().openGallery() stores the file in a temp folder and the FileSystemStorage doesn't help since it doesn't save with the original filename, rather a newly user-defined one.

Here's the code:

```
    uploadImg.addActionListener(e -> {

        Display.getInstance().openGallery(evt -> {
            String filePath = (String) evt.getSource();

            int fileNameIndex = filePath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1;
            String fileName = filePath.substring(fileNameIndex);
            System.out.println(fileName);

            System.out.println(filePath);
            try {
                InputStream is = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().openInputStream(filePath);
                Image i = Image.createImage(is);

                Image listingMask = resourceObjectInstance.getImage("refimg2.jpg");

                imgLabel.setIcon(i.fill(listingMask.getWidth(), listingMask.getHeight()));

                imgLabel.setHidden(false);
                refreshTheme();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex);
            }

        }, Display.GALLERY_IMAGE);
    });
```

For example, here's what I get when I print the different filepaths:

temp7907640882397406003..jpg
file://C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp/temp7907640882397406003..jpg

I want to know if there's a way to get the name of the file as shown in the image gallery, for instance: "hello.png".

---

Also, I have 2 datespinners. One being the start date of some event and the other, its end. I want the starting values of the 2nd datespinner to change dynamically depending on what has been selected in the first one. How can I achieve this? Otherwise, is there something else to use to do so?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: typos.

Edit 2: Datespinners.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [sample in the javadoc](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Display.html#openGallery-com.codename1.ui.events.ActionListener-int-):

```
hi.getToolbar().addCommandToRightBar(new Command("", icon) {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        Display.getInstance().openGallery((e) -> {
            if(e != null && e.getSource() != null) {
                String file = (String)e.getSource();
                try {
                    Media video = MediaManager.createMedia(file, true);
                    hi.removeAll();
                    hi.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, new MediaPlayer(video));
                    hi.revalidate();
                } catch(IOException err) {
                    Log.e(err);
                } 
            }
        }, Display.GALLERY_VIDEO);
    }
});
```

Comment: In the snippet above, the content of variable file contains the absolute path of the file. How to automatically retrieve only the file name (without the path) of the image?

Comment: `name.substring(name.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)`